# Can't test Ubuntu from CD

Tags: 12.10, boot, cd

When I'm trying to boot Linux by selecting ,,Try Linux,, in CD menu after 5 minutes of loading I see static screen with Ubuntu logo(dots are not blinking)

I also tried to boot from ,,install Linux,, but I had the same problem.

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: To rule out a media issue I would burn another CD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could have many reasons. Check the following steps:

- Is the CD damaged?

If the CD is damaged, the system might be unable to read certain data at some point. Also, your CD drive could be faulty. You can try installing Ubuntu via USB stick (tutorial for Windows [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and for Ubuntu [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)) to see if it's a problem with the CD (drive).

- How fast is your CPU? How much RAM do you have?

I personally experienced unexpectedly long waiting times when installing Ubuntu 12.04 or later on systems with poor hardware - especially on netbooks. I don't know how much time I waited, but I think one time I was waiting for about 10 minutes.^^ Don't worry, the operating system won't be so slow afterwards.